# How can I detect mouse wheel movement in QuickBasic?

Tags: basic, mouse

I am using the following code to trap left/right/middle mouse button and mouse row/column in Microsoft QuickBasic 4.5 and I need a way to detect the mouse wheel. I have looked at Ralf Brown's Interrupt List without luck.

The code requires the library QB.QLB.

```
DECLARE SUB Mouse.Function (Var1!, Var2!)

DIM SHARED MouseX AS INTEGER, MouseY AS INTEGER

TYPE RegTypeX
  AX AS INTEGER
  BX AS INTEGER
  CX AS INTEGER
  DX AS INTEGER
  BP AS INTEGER
  SI AS INTEGER
  DI AS INTEGER
  Flags AS INTEGER
  DS AS INTEGER
  ES AS INTEGER
END TYPE

COMMON SHARED InregsX AS RegTypeX
COMMON SHARED OutregsX AS RegTypeX

DECLARE SUB InterruptX (N AS INTEGER, I AS RegTypeX, O AS RegTypeX)

 CALL Mouse.Function(0, 0) ' init mouse
 CALL Mouse.Function(1, 0) ' show mouse
 DO

 IF LEN(INKEY$) THEN
    CALL Mouse.Function(2, 0) ' hide mouse
    EXIT DO
 END IF

  CALL Mouse.Function(3, 0)

 Var2 = INT((OutregsX.CX - 1) / 8 + 1)
 Var3 = INT((OutregsX.DX - 1) / 8 + 1)

 IF Var3 <> Mouse.Row OR Var2 <> Mouse.Column THEN
    CALL Mouse.Function(2, 0) ' hide mouse
    Mouse.Row = Var3
    Mouse.Column = Var2
    PRINT Mouse.Row, Mouse.Column
    CALL Mouse.Function(1, 0) ' show mouse
 END IF

 Mouse.Button = False
 CALL Mouse.Function(5, 0)
 IF (OutregsX.AX AND 1) = 1 THEN
    IF OutregsX.BX > False THEN
       Mouse.Button = -1
       PRINT "Left-Click"
    END IF
 END IF
 Mouse.Button2 = False
 CALL Mouse.Function(5, 1)
 IF (OutregsX.AX AND 2) = 2 THEN
    IF OutregsX.BX > False THEN
       Mouse.Button2 = -1
       PRINT "Right-Click"
    END IF
 END IF
 Mouse.Button3 = False
 CALL Mouse.Function(5, 2)
 IF (OutregsX.AX AND 4) = 4 THEN
    IF OutregsX.BX > False THEN
       Mouse.Button3 = -1
       PRINT "Middle-Click"
    END IF
 END IF
 LOOP
 END

SUB Mouse.Function (Var1, Var2)
   InregsX.AX = Var1
   InregsX.BX = Var2
   CALL InterruptX(&H33, InregsX, OutregsX)
END SUB
```

Any ideas?

I recently tried the following code to detect mousewheel in dosbox:

```
CALL Mouse.Function(5, -1)

Mouse.Wheel = 0
' check mousewheel in BX
Wheel = OutregsX.BX
IF Wheel THEN
   Mouse.Wheel = -1
   PRINT "MouseWheel"
   CALL Mouse.Function(0, 0)
END IF
```

this does not return anything.

Comment: Which mouse driver you are using? Not all support the wheel.

Comment: True, what's the environment (DOS/Windows/emulation) and what driver is used. The mouse wheel is a later add on. Some put it in the button list (Button 2 being press and 3/4 encoding rotation). Start would beto write a little test program monitoring driver function 3 which returns all buttons in BX. Simply read it in a loop while displaying the content of of BX as binary should show any assignment. (Since you don't use the clickcount, this would speed out your detection anyway.)

Comment: Cross-posted [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66221198/4500798).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By the time mice wheels became widely available (starting with the Microsoft IntelliMouse; the Genius EasyScroll was earlier, but we can ignore that here), support for DOS was a secondary concern, and the “standard” DOS drivers and tools never supported them. As a result, there are limited avenues for wheel support in DOS itself, and DOS emulation environments (such as Windows’ NTVDM, or even DOSBox) usually don’t support them.

The only documented API I’m aware of for wheel mice in DOS is [that provided](https://sourceforge.net/p/cutemouse/trunk/ci/master/tree/cutemouse/WHEELAPI.TXT) by [CuteMouse](http://cutemouse.sourceforge.net/). This works fine with CuteMouse running directly on the hardware, with a PS/2 wheel mouse, or in an environment which will emulate the appropriate PS/2 messages (for example, [DOSBox-X](https://dosbox-x.com/) with mouse wheel movement remapping disabled, and CuteMouse running).

This adds function 0x11 to interrupt 0x33 to check for wheel support: this will return 0x574D in `AX` and bit 0 set to 1 in `CX` is a wheel is supported. Existing functions are changed as follows:

- functions 0 and 0x21 clear the wheel movement counter;
- function 3 (get cursor position) returns the accumulated wheel movement in `BH`, as an 8-bit counter (counting since the last call to function 3, and functions 5 or 6 with `BX` set to -1);
- function 5 (get button press) recognises `BX` value -1 to query the wheel, returning the wheel movement in `AH` as an 8-bit signed counter, and when querying the wheel specifically, in `BX` as a 16-bit signed counter, with `CX` and `DX` giving the column and row where the wheel was last moved (wheel movement accumulates as for function 3);
- function 6 (get button release) is altered in the same way as function 5.

Functions 0xC and 0x14 can also be used to register a callback for wheel movement; see the CuteMouse documentation for details.

Mouse wheel clicks are represented as middle-button clicks.

In Quick BASIC, you’d use something like this to detect the wheel:

```
Mouse.Function(&H11, 0)
IF (OutregsX.AX = &H574D) AND ((OutregsX.CX AND 1) = 1) THEN
  PRINT "Mouse wheel present and supported"
ELSE
  PRINT "Mouse wheel not present and/or not supported"
END IF
```

If a wheel is present and supported, you’d then use

```
CALL Mouse.Function(5, -1)
IF OutregsX.BX > 0 THEN
  PRINT "Wheel moved down"
ELSE IF OutregsX.BX < 0 THEN
  PRINT "Wheel moved up"
END IF
```

At this point, the absolute value of `BX` gives the amount of wheel movement.

Comment: How does that indicate if the wheel has gone up or down?

Comment: I have not found your suggestions to work. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Have you looked at `mousetst.asm` in the CuteMouse source code? You could even start by running `mousetst`. Are you using CuteMouse? What environment are you testing in?

Comment: I am running DOSbox in Win10 with only default windows drivers installed.

Comment: I am not using CuteMouse nor do I want to look at assembly.

Comment: As far as I’m aware, you won’t be able to get mouse support without CuteMouse, unless you write your own mouse driver. I’ve added a BASIC example showing how to detect wheel support and presence.

Comment: I’ve added an example showing how to retrieve the movement too.

Comment: Mouse function x33 AX=&H11 returns number of buttons.

Comment: Are you using CuteMouse?

Comment: And as explained in the answer, the only way you can get this to work if you’re not running directly on the hardware is to use CuteMouse in DOSBox-X (or any other environment which produces wheel PS/2 messages).

Comment: I downloaded cutemouse - history.txt : usb works, wheel does not.

Comment: Please explain what you did in more detail: what environment did you use, how was it set up, and how did you run CuteMouse?

Comment: I understand your frustration, and that you’d prefer a simpler answer, but I’m afraid this is all there is...

Comment: I am only saying is that in line 70 of history.txt is ctmouse\doc states "usb works, wheel does not" and I quote such.

Comment: And at the beginning of the file, it says “Added new wheel API.” Newer entries in the history file supersede old ones. I’ve *tried* all this for you (apart from the QB code), it works.

Comment: I tried Ctmouse /O without any success. Could you try it in QB45??

Comment: Yes, I’ll give it a shot later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, I’m going to need a little more time...